# A wireless projector both for Windows & macOS?

Tags: wireless, projector

I'm looking for a projector which:

- has a resolution of 1080p or better
- an output of > 3999 lumen
- can be connected to wirelessly from Microsoft Windows 10 (Miracast?)
- can be connected to from Apple macOS

(It's my understanding that Miracast isn't really/really isn't supported on macOS?)

Who has any suggestions? We currently use a [BenQ MH740](http://www.benq.no/product/projector/mh740), and I've been ogling the [MH750](http://www.benq.no/product/projector/mh750) (with [QP01](http://www.benq.com/product/accessory/qcast_qp01/) dongle), but we're not married to BenQ so other brands are fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a 4200 lumen projector on Amazon.com by EUG:
[EUG 4200 lumen 1080p wireless](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TYBJE7Q)

It is compatible with a variety of different wireless casting programs including Airplay and Miracast.